# SQL: Help writing select query using JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

**Languages**

```
ID    LangName    LangAbbr
1     English     en
2     Spanish     es
```

**Strings**

```
ID    String
1     Hello
2     Goodbye
```

**Translations**

```
ID    LangID    StringID    Translation
1     1         1           Hello
2     2         1           Hola
3     1         2           Goodbye
4     2         2           Adios
```

As of now, I have had the ID of the language from the `languages` table, and ran a query to get all of the translations for that language:

```
SELECT t.Translation, s.String FROM Strings 
AS s JOIN Translations AS t ON s.ID = t.StringID 
AND LangID = :LangID
```

This works great. However, I needed to update some of my code elsewhere where now I will no longer have access to the `LangID`, but instead, only the `LangAbbr` from the `Languages` table (which up until now was not used in this query).

My question is, how do I update this query to perform the following:

1. Get the `ID` from the `Languages` table whose `LangAbbr` = X (my
   variable)
2. Using that ID, return an array whose keys equal the names of each `String` in the `Strings` table, and whose values equal the
   `Translation` in the `Translations` table for that string/language ID.

Comment: So as a SQL result set, are you looking for pairs given `es` as `Hello, Hola | Goodbye, Adios`? (formatted as an array which is relevant to your application code but less to the SQL)

Comment: Looking for `array('String' => 'Translation')`, like if the language is Spanish, `array('Hello' => 'Hola')`

Comment: Bur you are looking for _all_ string translations for a given language, correct? Not just one specific translation?

Comment: And do you need to return a null value for the string if no translation exists, or perhaps the untranslated string as the value?

Comment: All translations that exist for the given language. If strings exists but a translation doesn't in that language, it doesn't need to return empty. I just need an array of every string that exists in the specified language. Array key being the string name and array value being the translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really only need to add another join through `Strings` to `Languages` and since you don't have a requirement to return untranslated strings for a given language there's nothing complicated.  To return all Spanish strings as a `String,Translation` pair for exampel, the SQL would be (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30273/4):

```
SELECT 
  String,
  Translation
FROM
  strings s
  INNER JOIN translations t ON s.ID = t.StringID
  INNER JOIN languages l ON t.LangID = l.ID
-- use PDO param :langAbbr
WHERE LangAbbr = 'es'
```

Based on your comment I'll assume you are using PHP/PDO. The fetch loop can be structured to set array keys as:

```
// Assuming a successful prepare()/execute() of the above query
// into $stmt
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_from_above);
$stmt->execute(array(':langAbbr' => 'es'));

$translations = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  // Index the $translations array by String during the fetch
  $translations[$row['String']] = $row['Translation'];
}
```

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you. One of these days I'll come across an article that teaches `JOIN` queries that clicks. I've read many, but none of them really hit home. Thanks again.

Comment: I usually think of it as a chain, starting from what you know is static (`Strings`) and linking backward through every table needed to get all the columns you need as output and apply `WHERE` filters.  Sometimes the chain has to loop back on itself if where one table is actually used more than once. Not sure if this image helps or complicates...